# log4net issue in web service

Tags: log4net

We are successfully using log4net in our UI Layer but when we are testing in Webservice layer it does not work.

Here is the code in UI Layer:

```cs
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{

  ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(_Default));


  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      ServiceReference1.IService1 is1 = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
      is1.GetData(1);

      logger.Info("Hello Nine Thanks for use Log4Net,This is info message");
      logger.Debug("Hello Nine Thanks for use Log4Net,This is Debug message");
      logger.Error("Hello Nine Thanks for use Log4Net,This is Error message");
      logger.Warn("Hello Nine Thanks for use Log4Net,This is Warn message");
      logger.Fatal("Hello Nine Thanks for use Log4Net,This is Fatal message");

  }
}
```

---

Here is the web.config settings for the UI Layer:

```xml
<log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="MyloggerSite2.log"/> <!-- This is logging in app root folder -->

        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-2p %c [%x] - %m%n"/>

        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
  <level value="All"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    </root>
</log4net>
```

---

Here is the code in ServiceLayer which does not work although it it is the same as above for the most:

```cs
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Service1));

        logger.Info("Hello Nine Thanks for use Log4Net,This is info message");
        logger.Debug("Hello Nine Thanks for use Log4Net,This is Debug message");
        logger.Error("Hello Nine Thanks for use Log4Net,This is Error message");
        logger.Warn("Hello Nine Thanks for use Log4Net,This is Warn message");
        logger.Fatal("Hello Nine Thanks for use Log4Net,This is Fatal message");

        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
 }
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.
Thanks,
N

Answer (score 3):

Do you configure log4net for instance by having an attribute like this in your web service:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan for the response. I have added it like this for both class & the method but not sure if you meant it like this :[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
        public string GetData(int value)
        {                                 But no luck

Comment: I assumed that it would be clear how to use an assembly level attribute... but you seem to have figured out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have just added this attribute manually in AssemblyInfo.cs:

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]

It works.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Just add below assembly in web config file of your service's project.

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

Comment: Not in web config, but in AssemblyInfo.cs, as stated already.